# Validation rule for Multi picklist

Tags: validation-rule, multi-select

I have a requirement where if a value "Others" from a Multi picklist is selected, "please explain others" text box should be used, if any other value from Multi picklist is selected then "please explain others" text box should not be used.

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Others'),
    ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c)
)
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Common Cold')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Strep Throat')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'CoVID-19')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Flu')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Sinus')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'UTI')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Whooping cough')
) &
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'None')
) &
NOT(ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the validation that you need:

```
OR(
    AND(
        INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Others'),
        ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c)
    ),
    AND(
        NOT(INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Others')),
        NOT(ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c))
    )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Dhimitër Stambolliu

Comment: Thank you @HM. If the answer helped you, you can mark it as correct so it can help others in the community. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's... a few things wrong with this formula. In terms of syntax:

- Formulas need to return a single value, and your first `AND()` is not connected to the rest of your formula
- `&` isn't a logical AND operator, it's for string concatenation (`&&` and `AND()` are the logical AND operator/function)
- `AND()` should generally take multiple parameters. It's not a syntax error if it only contains one thing, but that is a red flag (a warning that there may be other issues)

### Fixing the syntax errors

So if we were to fix those, your formula would end up like

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Others'),
    ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c)
)
&&
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Common Cold'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Strep Throat'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'CoVID-19'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Flu'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Sinus'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'UTI'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Whooping cough'),
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'None'),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Other_Existing_Infections__c))
)
```

`&&` and `AND()` are functionally equivalent (as are `||` and `OR()`, as well as `!` and `NOT()`). It's generally a better idea to pick one (operators or functions) and stick with it. Mixing them isn't a syntax error, but it's more likely that you'll make a mistake.

### While that is syntactically correct, it is still semantically wrong

The two big semantic issues here are:

- Validation rules trigger when the result is true (not when the result is false)
- When you're checking if a field has one of a number of values, you want to use `OR()` instead of `AND()`

  - On a similar note, when checking if a field does not equal any of a number of values, you want to use `AND()` instead of `OR()`

Multipicklists are a bit different (because they can hold multiple values), but if you

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'Common Cold'),
    ...
    INCLUDES(Existing_Infections__c , 'None')
)
```

then that entire `AND()` is only true when *every one of those picklist values are selected*. That's definitely not what you wanted. So the correct approach would be to use `OR()` here instead of `AND()`.

While that would work, checking individually for each of the other possible multipicklist values is a bit of wasted effort. All you really need here is to know that:

- The multipicklist is not blank
- The multipicklist does not include "Others"

So now you have two main condition sets that you're working with

- Existing infections includes "Others" (let's call this "X") and the Other Existing Infections field is blank (let's call this "Y" from here on)
- Existing infections is not blank (let's call this "Z"), and the Other Existing Infections field is not blank (this is "NOT(Y)", or the opposite of Y)

Keeping in mind that validation rules trigger when the result is true, the correct formula here would be

```
OR(
    AND(X, Y),
    AND(Z, NOT(Y))
)
```

The outermost function needs to be an `OR()` here because either one of those two main conditions being true is enough to make the data invalid according to your description.